# Is it idiomatic to use two past progressives for sequential things when answering a question asked in the past progressive tense?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Supposing somebody asks you: "What *were you doing* from 6 p.m. until your brother called on you at 9 p.m?

Which answer(s) is/are idiomatic when listing more than one thing?

1. "I was feeding the rabbits at 6:30 and then I was watching the birds"
2. "I was feeding the rabbits at 6:30 and then I watched the birds."
3. "I fed the rabbits and then I watched the birds." (I'm guessing this is an idiomatic answer.)
4. "I was feeding the rabbits at 6:30 and then I was watching the birds at 8:00."
5. "I fed the rabbits at 6:30 and then I watched the birds at 8:00." (It probably means I started feeding the rabbits at 6:30 and watching the birds at 8:00.)

Comment: Unless you keep a large number of rabbits, presumably it doesn't take very long to feed them, so I wouldn't expect a progressive tense to be used.  On the contrary, watching birds is an ongoing activity, so you might say "I started watching the birds at 8.00" or "I was watching the birds from 8.00 until he arrived" (assuming it was a summer evening when it stays light until late!)

Comment: @KateBunting your sentences seem reasonable. But my question is not about that. It's about whether it's idiomatic to use two progressive tenses for two things stated in sequential order.

Comment: We don't use 'at [time]' with a progressive tense. You could say "I was doing my homework until 7.30, then I was watching a film until 8.45", though it would probably be more natural to say "..then I started watching a film".